# What is difference between Phase shift keying (PSK) and Quadrature Amplitude Modulation (QAM) mathematical equation

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

I went through a literature and found the following **expression for PSK signal**. On this basis, what will be the equation for **QAM signal **. Also from where i would be able to read about this equation of PSK and QAM. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.
$$s\left[n \right] = \sqrt{P_s}\exp \left(j \frac{2\pi k}{M} \right)$$

Comment: When you did a web search on "QAM vs PSK", how many *other* references did you find?  Which ones weren't clear?

Comment: Theoretically I had understood, but what will be the mathematical equation similar to that of PSK

Comment: Why do you need an equation? As long as you know the constellation points, I can't think of a reason why you'd need one

Comment: Put less strongly, but leading to the same result -- you should be able to look at the constellation points and come up with the equation.  Is that where you're having trouble?

Comment: I looked at constellation points and also understood the equations. For e.g., in case of BPSK we get the two equations: S1(t) = Ac*Cos(2*Pi*fc*t) for bit 0 and S2(t) =  Ac*Cos(2*Pi*fc*t+Pi) for bit 1. But these equations are not in the above mentioned form i.e., in the form of exponential.

Comment: Charu, have you look at the constellation diagram? Why should an easy formula to generate a lattice in cartesian coordinates be a complex exponential? It feels like you're not really trying to understand the formula...

Comment: @charu The signal in your question is a complex number, not PSK.

Comment: @mbaz can we have such complex number representation for QAM signal also?

Comment: @charu A QAM _pulse_ can be represented by a complex number. A QAM signal is a sequence of such pulses, and can be represented also by a sequence of complex numbers.

Comment: @Mbaz can you mention the exactly how that sequence is...